# Cannot connect to Apache HTTP Server from outside after awhile

Tags: php, apache, http

we have a problem with our Website not beeing accessible from outside (not localhost) after some time (2-3 days).

We use an Apache HTTP Server 2.4. There are 4 Websites hosted on the Server, mainly using port 443 using a self signed server certificate. So far, everything is running fine. Since I added a new Website using Alias directive and PHP, after a while **all** Websites are not accessible from remote anymore. However, I can access them from localhost on the server.

The error log does not show any entries at the time the websites are not accessible anymore. We currently fix the problem by simply restarting the Apache HTTP Server and everything is back to normal. The problem is, that we need the service to be available 24/7.

This is the current httpd.conf:

```
Listen 443
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
    ServerName myserver.net:443

    Alias /site2 "${WEBROOT}/site2"
    Alias /site3 "${WEBROOT}/site3"

    ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html index.php

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
LoadModule php5_module "${PHPROOT}/php5apache2_4.dll"
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "${PHPROOT}"
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone have an idea where to look at? Would very much appreciate.

**UPDATE**

The server was running for 13 days, and then we had to restart it due to some configuration changes. It took 1 day and the problem came back. I looked at the server-status page, but i cannot find a clue what might be the problem:

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.16 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12
Server MPM: WinNT
Server Built: Jul 13 2015 12:31:58
Distributed by: The Apache Haus
Compiled with: Visual Studio 2012
Current Time: Tuesday, 06-Oct-2015 11:38:01 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
Restart Time: Sunday, 04-Oct-2015 23:40:51 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 1 day 11 hours 57 minutes 9 seconds
Server load: -1.00 -1.00 -1.00
Total accesses: 326772 - Total Traffic: 4.2 GB
2.52 requests/sec - 33.8 kB/second - 13.4 kB/request
1 requests currently being processed, 63 idle workers
```

Comment: If it's accessible from the inside but not the outside it's more likely a firewall issue.

Comment: @Capsule so you think that something is closing the ports for the firewall? is apache reconfigurating the firewall on restart?

Comment: No, but it may free-up stuck connections and tell the firewall it's OK to accept new ones again. You should activate Apache's  `server-status` and check what's going on before restarting it. You might see a number of Kee-Alive connections that shouldn't be there anymore, or some other weird stuff.

Comment: @Capsule i managed to see the server-status page. the servers uptime is now 6 days 3 hours. i do see an increasing amount of idle workers every day (now 63). any thoughts what the problem might be? you want to see the complete status page?

Comment: I would have recommended to limit the number of spare processes or threads but apparently you can't do that in Windows, according to this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_winnt.html. You should try to figure out what's the number of idle workers once you can't access the server from the outside anymore, maybe you're onto something.

Comment: hey, i am still struggeling with that problem. i was reading the documentations about performance tweaks with mpm modules, but there is no `LoadModule` entry in the httpd.conf and there is also no `mod_mpm...` file in the modules folder of the Apache24 installation. do i have to reinstall the apache server?

Comment: Some modules are built-in, that explains why you don't need to load them (and you can't find them in the modules folder)

Comment: i managed to see the firewall log of the windows firewall. at the time the error occurs, there are no "drop" entries in the log for the ports 433 or 80. still no solution in sight

Comment: i install a new apache webserver with PHP7 on another virtual server. the problem occurred after 3 hours. all https addresses are not accessible from outside, although there is one http website that can be accessed. i guess that there is a problem with the SSL cache or something?!

Comment: Another reason not to run Apache and PHP on Windows I guess. I never had such an issue on Linux in almost 20 years

Comment: Did you solve this error ?

Comment: @Abkarino unfortunately not. we completely gave up on this error and deactivated the Apache HTTP Server and are currently using IIS. it is easier to use, but the user management is a bit stupid.

Answer (score 1):

AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

When this happens, the error.log should show "Asyncroneous AcceptEx Failed" and something about 'Network name no longer available'.

These two directives are the replacement for Win32DisableAcceptEx in Apache 2.2.x.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply. could you please explain a bit more in detail your answer. i have currently no idea what you are talking about. i guess there must be something changed in the config file?